# Create a function in webrdriverio

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I have recently switched from Selenium (Java) to webdriverio.

In Java, I had to used to have helper function which accepted webelement as argument.

```
public WebElement clickOnEle(Webelement element) {
    // Code here
}
```

I want to create a similar function in Webdriverio using typescript.

For example:

```
    static async clickOnElement(elementToClk) {
        console.log("Clicking on element: " + elementToClk)
        $(elementToClk).click();
        console.log("Element clicked")
    }
```

Here I want to define the type of elementToClk as webelement `(elementToClk: webelement)`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use below

```html
async function clickOnEle(ele){
  await ele.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 100000});
  await ele.click();
}

  await clickOnEle($("locator"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).